# ValueError: invalid color argument in my pygame code

Tags: python, pygame

I wrote the code for my final project. It's a code that makes a bouncing on the wall. I wanted to make two balls, so I created a class and created several functions. But I think that my code is not working.

```
ValueError: invalid color argument in my pygame code
```

---

```
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()  
screensize = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Final project") 

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

radius = 25  # 공의 크기
color_list = [RED, BLUE, GREEN]

x = 0
y = 0
x1 = 0
y1 = 0
dx = 2
dy = 2
color = color_list


class ball:

def create_ball(self):
    self.x = random.randint(radius, screensize[0]-radius)
    self.y = random.randint(radius, screensize[1]-radius)
    self.x1 = random.randint(radius, screensize[0]-radius)
    self.y1 = random.randint(radius, screensize[1]-radius)
    self.color = random.choice(color_list)

def move_ball(self):
    self.x = x + dx
    self.y = y + dy
if not radius < x < screensize[0]-radius:
    dx = -dx
    color = random.choice(color_list)
elif not radius < y < screensize[1]-radius:
    dy = -dy
    color = random.choice(color_list)

def move_ball1(self):
    self.x1 = x1 + dx
    self.y1 = y1 + dy
if not radius < x1 < screensize[0]-radius:
    dx = -dx
    color = random.choice(color_list)
elif not radius < y1 < screensize[1]-radius:
    dy = -dy
    color = random.choice(color_list)


b = ball()
print(b)


go = True
while go:
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
    clock.tick(150) 
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            go = False  

    screen.fill(WHITE)  
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x, y), radius)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, (x1, y1), radius)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Can you paste full traceback of error?

Answer (score 4):

According to [`Pygame` docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.circle), `pygame.draw.circle()` function takes color argument as `int` or `tuple`, not `list`. So it should look like:

```
pygame.draw.circle(screen, BLUE, (x, y), radius)
```

Comment: This is not the intent of the code in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The `color` needs to be a color value. Therefore you have to select a random color from the list of colors:

<s>`color = color_list`</s>

```py
color = random.choice(color_list)
```

---

Read about [Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html)  and [Instance Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects) and use them in the correct way. You just need 1 `Ball` class with 1 `move` and 1 `draw` method. However, you can create as many instances of this class as you want (e.g.: `b1` and `b2`):

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()  
screensize = (800, 600)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize) 
pygame.display.set_caption("Final project") 

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

radius = 25  # 공의 크기
color_list = [RED, BLUE, GREEN]

class Ball:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(radius, screensize[0]-radius)
        self.y = random.randint(radius, screensize[1]-radius)
        self.dx = 2
        self.dy = 2
        self.color = random.choice(color_list)

    def move(self):
        self.x += self.dx
        self.y += self.dy
        if not radius < self.x < screensize[0]-radius:
            self.dx = -self.dx
            self.color = random.choice(color_list)
        elif not radius < self.y < screensize[1]-radius:
            self.dy = -self.dy
            self.color = random.choice(color_list)

    def draw(self, surf):
        pygame.draw.circle(surf, self.color, (self.x, self.y), radius)

b1 = Ball()
b2 = Ball()

go = True
while go:
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
    clock.tick(150) 
    for event in pygame.event.get():  
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:  
            go = False  

    b1.move()
    b2.move()

    screen.fill(WHITE)  
    b1.draw(screen)
    b2.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
```